# Is it possible to access a previously-created variable without knowing its name?

Tags: python, variables

I have a code:

```
globals()['a%s' % int(x+1)] = someclass(some_things)
asmenys.append(y)
```

How could I make `y` the variable that I added (that's in a loop)? (Don't be angry with the use of the `globals` method; it's for some reasons.)

Comment: This is a genuinely terrible idea. Could you expand on the *"some reasons"*?

Comment: @jonrsharpe that's thing's in the touple need to be named:)

Comment: Then why not use a `collections.namedtuple`, or just a `dict`? There is *almost always* a better option than messing about with `globals`. Could you provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of *what you're actually trying to achieve*?

Comment: @jonrsharpe So is thre a way wihout changing tons of my beutiful code? :)

Comment: Without a lot more information, it's very difficult to say. **Edit the question**, explain what you're doing and why, and you might find that you get more helpful answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you asking how to extract the variables from the dict returned by `globals()` that were created dynamically? If so, it can't be done. `globals()` does not discriminate between statically and dynamically created variables.

Furthermore, while variables can be extracted from a scope through the use of `globals()` or `locals()`, chances are there is a better way to solve your problem. If you could tell us *why* you need this, perhaps we could point you in a different (doable and correct/idiomatic) direction.

If your goal is to add a value to the dict returned by `globals()`, and you absolutely need to do it this way, you do it like you would with any other dict:

```
globals()["a"] = "asd"
print globals()["a"]
```

The above prints `asd`.

Comment: I'm asking how to add the added variable to the list

Comment: @ignasaskielasas if `asmenys` is a tuple (note spelling) then you can't `append` to it - **tuples are immutable**.